# iPhone - Dismiss keyboard so that UIToolbar remains

Tags: ios, iphone, uitoolbar

I'm developing an iPhone app where I had to add a **`UIToolbar`** whenever a keyboard appears.
[image: When textview is clicked]

Now when I dismiss the keyboard, `[textView resignFirstResponder]` the whole UIToolbar gets dismissed from the view. What I would like to achieve is dismiss the keyboard to a certain Y point so that the UIToolbar remains at the bottom. 
[image: when keyboard is dismissed]

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT** UIToolbar Code

```
UIButton *firstButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 81, 45)];
[firstButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"askQuestionCloseButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *secondButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(79, 0, 80, 45)];
[secondButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"askQuestionUploadPic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *thirdButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(158, 0, 80, 45)];
[thirdButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"askQuestionSetLocation.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[thirdButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


UIButton *fourthButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(238, 0, 80, 45)];
[fourthButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"askQuestionPost.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[fourthButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


UIView *leftBarItemsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
[leftBarItemsView addSubview:firstButton];
[leftBarItemsView addSubview:secondButton];
[leftBarItemsView addSubview:thirdButton];
[leftBarItemsView addSubview:fourthButton];

//spacer
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
spacer.width = -12;

UIBarButtonItem *leftBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftBarItemsView ];


UIToolbar *tipToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 47)];
tipToolbar.barStyle = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

tipToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, leftBarItem, spacer, nil];
self.askQuestionTextField.inputAccessoryView = tipToolbar;
```

Comment: where you add toolbar in your code ? show your code for reference ?

Comment: @NANNAV Have edited the question . Please check the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` notifications to track keyboard visibility and when keyboard is visible then change the frame of your toolbar.

Example :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif{
     // Change the frame of your toolbar
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notif{
     // Change the frame of your toolbar
}
```